# Windows Server 2016 - Folder Redirection for Start menu -> right-click Windows PowerShell: "Windows cannot access ...Windows PowerShell.lnk"

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, folder-redirection

When I run this, PowerShell opens as expected:

```
    "\\Win-FileServer\Folder Redirection\myUsername\AppData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk"
```

- Also when I right-click the Start Menu and run PowerShell while logged in as my user on the Domain Controller, PowerShell opens as expected.

However, we have this issue on our RDS servers:

**When I right-click the start menu -> Windows PowerShell (admin or not), I get this error:**

```
    Windows cannot access \\Win-FileServer\Folder Redirection\myUsername\AppData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk

    Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.
```

```
    Error code: 0x80070002
```

Checking RSoP I **only** see Favorites being redirected to the file server, nothing else. I cannot disable Start Menu redirection because it's already "not configured."

Update:

- When deploying a new Win Svr 2016 VM we do not see this issue.
- However, when creating a new AD user and logging in to either of the two RDS servers, the issue persists, so **issue is machine specific** (not profile specific).

[image: WinSvr-2016-folder-redirection-issue]

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but my system shows it as being in ...\AppData\Roaming\... (this is on Windows 10)

Comment: `I cannot disable Start Menu redirection because it's already "not configured."` That may not resolve it if redirection was previously configured. Was it?

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I'm not sure if it ever was enabled before. I can try enable and disabling it now if that could help...?

Comment: Thanks, Davidw. That's N/A in this case since this is WinSvr 2016

Comment: Folder Redirection policies may be tattooed on a profile and need to be cleaned up. Just as it would need to be on a desktop.

Comment: Thanks, @GregAskew. To be sure, you mean testing with a different user and if the issue doesn't persist there, recreating the original profile?

Comment: @SamAndrew81 Just took a look at Windows Server 2016, it's still ...\appdata\roaming\...

Comment: Still no resolution. Tried a new profile, same issue.